# Running Cypress from the command line and pointing to a folder of tests

Tags: node.js, cypress

Trying to set up Cypress to run on a server which has no access to npm. The final goal is to have it running as part of our CI but my first step is to prove it can be from the command line.

I have downloaded Cypress directly from the CDN and installed it on the server at `C:\Program Files\Cypress`.

I have a set of Cypress tests at `D:\demo\cypress-tests-main`.

When in `C:\Program Files\Cypress`, I can run Cypress to get the dashboard and run tests by just typing the command `Cypress`.

Using the dashboard I can then browse to '''D:\demo\cypress-tests-main''' and successfully run the tests.

Now I am trying to work out how to specify the location of the tests on the command line but am having no joy.

I was expecting to be able to do something like

`%PROGRAMFILES%\cypress "D:\demo\cypress-tests-main"`

The online help appears to assume you have access to npm for the machine where the tests are being run, which is not the case here.

I have tried ```set config CYPRESS_RUN_BINARY=%PROGRAMFILES%/Cypress/Cypress.exe''' in Node.js but have not seen any benefit from that.

I've got a feeling there is some fundamental item I have failed to grasp here. It's the first time I have used Node.js so that's a distinct possibility.

Could anyone provide any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

I move to the test project directory and referenced cypress in the command line from there. as follows

D:\demo\cypress-tests-main>D:/Cypress/cypress.exe run